# How to fix 'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I' just started coding with flutter and got this problem with text widget it throws "Failed assertion: line 241 pos 10: 'data != null'" on the second page of the app

I tried changing "list.title" to "hello" but it didn't work, and also if i use text widget in the first page it works fine

```
 // go to second page code
 viewTodoList(BuildContext context,TodoList item){
    assert(item!=null);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context,TodoListView.routeName,arguments: item);
}

// second page code
class TodoListView extends StatefulWidget {
    static const routeName ="/todo_list_view";
    TodoListView({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
   _TodoListViewState createState() => _TodoListViewState();
}
class _TodoListViewState extends State<TodoListView> {

    final TodoList list=ModalRoute.of().settings.arguments;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
               title: Text(widget.title),
            ),//appBar
            body: Text(list.title),

        );//Scaffold
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page2 constructor is expecting a title:

```
TodoListView({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

But you aren't passing it when you're calling the page:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,TodoListView.routeName,arguments: item);
```

If it isn't passed it's `null`  (That's your problem).

You cold pass it when you configure your named routes:

```
MaterialApp(
...
    routes: [
        TodoListView.routeName: (BuildContext context) => TodoListView(title:'Page 2'),
]
...
)
```

But if you going to get it fixed, you should put it in the TodoListView.

A null safe exemple:

```
        Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
               title: Text('Page 2'),
            ),//appBar
            body: Text(list?.title ?? ''),

        );//Scaffold
```

Comment: thanks i didn't need the title passed and i was thinking that "Text(list.title)" was the problem. I think it would be better if we can get the error line like on any other programming language

Answer (score 1):

Change the `body: Text(list.title)` to `Text("${list.title}")`

Same goes for the others like widget.title for example, same idea

Answer (score 0):

Just give a default value in case you have a null `Text(widget.title ?? "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // go to second page code
 viewTodoList(BuildContext context,TodoList item){
    assert(item!=null);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context,TodoListView.routeName,arguments: item);
}

// second page code
class TodoListView extends StatefulWidget {
    static const routeName ="/todo_list_view";
    TodoListView({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
   _TodoListViewState createState() => _TodoListViewState();
}
class _TodoListViewState extends State<TodoListView> {

    final TodoList list=ModalRoute.of().settings.arguments;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
               title: Text(widget.title ?? ""),
            ),//appBar
            body: Text(list.title ?? ""),

        );//Scaffold
  }
```